# Is there a way to export Cloudwatch logs into Amazon S3 using AWS Lambda in a streaming way? (in Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Now I need to export logs in Cloudwatch into Amazon S3 in a streaming way using Lambda. I search the Internet and work out some code.

```
import boto3
import calendar
import 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO: create an export task from Cloudwatch logs
    #   and export the logs into Amazon S3

    # create client
    client= boto3.client("logs")

    # create export task
    response= client.create_export_task(
        taskName='logs-to-s3-task',
        logGroupName='ec2',
        fromTime= 123, # begin-time
        to=123, # end-time
        destination='some-s3',
        destinationPrefix='ec2-logs'
    )

    print("Response of logs-to-s3 lambda function: "+response)
```

And also I set up a trigger on the Cloudwatch logs that I want to export. But here comes several questions:

1. How can I make sure there is an update on S3 once there are any changes on Cloudwatch logs.
2. What's the logic of lambda's trigger. By its name, it should work like a listener on something/changes.
3. If it works as a listener, namely invoked when there is any change in Cloudwatch logs, how can I update only the newly-added logs into S3 rather than all logs within a time range. Or in another way, how can know the most recent update in S3 so that I can export data after that into S3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda function can subscribe to CloudWatch logs , and it will acts as a listener and lambda function will be triggered on cloud watch log events.

See this example in AWS documentation for reference --
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample

To update only the newly added logs into s3, you can write that particular event as an object to s3 with timestamp ordered using boto3 s3 client.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So basically, each generated logs will be a event triggering the code in lambda if I understand correctly? And then what I need to do is to import this event to S3 ( in this way I don't need to care about the timestamps anymore because one event one log). Is this correct?

Comment: What value did you specify for from and to time